# Data is not sent with http response in my http server

Tags: http, header, send

I'm working on making an HTTP server for my class.  But, the returned file is not being displayed by Firefox.  I construct a response header and put in the right `content-length` of the file I want to send, then I send the response headers with a call to `send()`.  Next I use `send()` again to send the file, why is Firefox not displaying the file?  I'll post the relevant code below.

As you'll see with the code, I am having trouble sending an `error_response`, during a 404 error.  Using live http headers I can see that Firefox receives the correct response header, and the `cout << error_response << endl;` does print the correct response.  Why doesn't Firefox display it?  Do I need to make only one call to `send()` containing the header and the response packet?

```
// send response headers
    response->Print( buffer, 2000 );
    if ( send( acc_tcp_sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0 ) < 0 ) {
      cerr << "Unable to send response headers to client." << endl;
      return 5;
    }

    // if 200 and GET then send file
    if ( response->Get_code() == 200 && method == "GET" ) {
      // send file
    }

    // close file, if it has been opened
    if ( response->Get_code() == 200 ) {
      fclose( returned_file );
    }
    else if ( method == "GET" ) {
      if ( send( acc_tcp_sock, error_response.c_str(), error_response.length(), 0 ) < 0 ) {
        cerr << "Unable to send data to client." << endl;
        return 6;
      }
      cout << error_response << endl;
    }

    close( acc_tcp_sock ); // close the connection
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried sending the response header *and* the file in the same send command? 
Is there a way you can tell what firefox is receiving. You could try writing, using some HTTPRequester class, a console app that sends a HTTP request to your server and see what its getting in return.

Comment: I could try that and I think it would probably work, but is it a requirement to do it that way?  What if the file is too big to completely buffer into memory and you have to do multiple sends?